# OptaPlanner Wrong Input: Want to use the DB instead of XML

Tags: java, sql, optaplanner

I am using OptaPlanner to create a scheduling plan for something instead of taking input from XML, I am trying to import the data from the dB directly, but it is still searching for the XML input, what might be the reason and how can it be corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn [JPA-Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/), remove the XStream annotations from the domain objects, add JPA annotations on the domain objects and replace the SolutionDao class with something that uses EntityManager instead of XStream.

Comment: can you give me some references to go about with learning JPA-Hibernate

Comment: Updated answer with link :)

Comment: i tried using the xstream annotations and referred the elements from the dB, but resulted in java: out of memory; will try through JPA as well. Thanks